# cc-by derivative or original crediting for just a part of a 3D model?

Tags: derivative-works, cc-by

**cc-by** derivative or original crediting for just a part of a  3D model?

Lets say I got a car and I just want one tire.

The original work is the whole car, not only the tires, it could be  called like "foo car".

My derivative now is just one tire. I dont want in my project the whole car, only one tire.

How do I credit it? Do I keep the original credit? Like:

> foo car by dude is ... ccby

But foo car is not there.. who reads the credits will think who created foo car forgot to add the other parts. **Or am I free to be *descriptive*** about how I just extracted a part of the original work? Like:

> foo car by dude is ... ccby. This project, by me, just extracted a part foo car without creatively modifying (only converted or adjusted to fit this project) the mesh (only decimated or remeshed) nor textures in a creative way (only down or upscaled) and is using only one tire under ccby. if you reuse this tire you must credit not me but dude, even if you use just an extracted  part of this tire.

Or?:

> foo tire is derivative of foo car ... under ccby.

Obs.: I understand minor adjustments, like blurring a texture, are not creative and doesnt allow me to publish as derivative right? It must be something clearly perceptible right?

Ps.: Btw, the answer for the above would also  apply to the case where i mix many extracted parts of many ccby works into a single model (like a chimera) rigged by me (or a mix of originals riggings)? Of course crediting everyone and detailing what part was taken from what model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take just a part of an original work to use in your work, it is good to be descriptive in your credits about using just a part of the original.

To go with your foo-car example, the credits could look like this:

> "Stack of tires" by VeganEye, licensed under CC-BY.
> Re-used and modified a part from foo-car by dude, licensed under CC-BY.

Or, if you want to be more explicit

> "Stack of tires" by VeganEye, licensed under CC-BY.
> Re-used and modified left front tire from foo-car by dude, licensed under CC-BY

This form of descriptive attribution also extends nicely to the case where you combine bits and pieces from multiple works

Comment: Thx! But also, should i credit myself that i did the dismembering? Because crediting myself feels like i am creating a derivative work, while it is not a derivative as i didnt modify it creatively. The point is, i cant credit myself, is it wrong to do that, or there is no problem on doing that? Not that i care being credited, but to other ppl know who did it and to further inform others that the dismembering was not prepared by them.

Comment: @VeganEye, you can claim the copyrights on the changes you made that resulted in the new work. I would avoid terms like "dismembered" because that makes it sound like you destroyed something tangible. You did not do that, you re-used a part of someone else's work to create something new.

Comment: Dismember is used in video games about virtual things that cause no real harm. But i agree that for a license it is indeed inadequate/wrong.

Comment: Cutting things apart is probably creative enough for copyright law purposes.

Comment: @jpa: An extracted portion of a work may be a derivative work worthy of its own protection if the choice of what to include and omit could not be concisely and unambiguously described.  A description like "remove all but the left wheel" would be insufficient to justify protection, and if arbitrary people given that description and an original work would produce identical models, the model would not embody any new creativity.